# Why my code is causing the segmentation fault?

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, ide

I tried to run this program in Visual stdio and used **WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB**
as input. After running it, it's showing `Segmentation fault (core dumped).`

How to solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char string[201];
    int i, j;
    scanf("%s",string);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(string); i++){
        if(string[i]=='W' && string[i+1]=='U' && string[i+2]=='B'){
            for(int k=i; k<i+3; k++){
                string[k]='o';
                i=i+2;
            }
        }
    }
    puts (string);

}
```

I want to know whats wrong with my program here

Comment: No. I want to know what's wrong with my program here.

Comment: @PronaySarker You are iterating over your string in a wrong way. Just run your code in debug mode and see what's wrong. I think it's your if statement.

Comment: It seems your question was closed because the title ask for a question that is already answered. But actually, you really want to know what in your code is causing the segmentation fault. It is probably a good idea to have your question title reflect what you really want! Think about it for your next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access `string[i+2]` when I is equal to `strlen(string) - 1`. You can access string[i+1] which will be the terminating nul char.

Change the upper limit of you for loop.